# Disable table cell resizing

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table which has two cells (`<td>`) which as a width of 0px. I inserted one `<div>` in them with some text. The cells with 0px width then expanded showing the content. I don't want this happen. I want those two cells to hide as if there is no content inside. I don't want to do this using `visibility` or `overflow` attribute.

You can see an example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/cNmNH/)**

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try to set "overflow: hidden;" ? (with width: 0px)

Comment: Have you tried using display:none on either the div or the td?

Comment: @A.B.Cade i tried setting overflow: hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cNmNH/4/

```
#frame2, #frame3 {
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```